# Getting UserStory Milestones.TargetDate on Rally

Tags: rally

What i'm trying to do is to get the milestones TargetDate from my stories. This is what i have for now:

```
    var estimatedTasksQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                model: 'UserStory',
                limit: Infinity,
                fetch: [ 'Milestones', 'AcceptedDate', 'PlanEstimate', 'ScheduleState', 'Iteration'],
                filters: [ 
                    {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
                     operator: '=',
                     value: '0'}
                ]
    });

    estimatedTasksQuery.load({
            callback: function(store) {
                    store.each(function(record) {
                        if (record.get('Milestones').Count != 0){
                           console.log(record.get('Milestones'));
                        }
                    });
            }
    });
```

As you can see in the "Milestones" structure bellow the TargetDate attribute doesnt appear.

Console:

```
Count: 1
_rallyAPIMajor: "2"
_rallyAPIMinor: "0"
_ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/123123/Milestones"
_tagsNameArray: Array[1]
    0: Object
       DisplayColor: "#848689"
       Name: "2.06"
       _ref: "/milestone/123123"
       __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
_type: "Milestone"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this with the API as it exists.  That _tagsNameArray that is populated on the Milestones collection on each returned story is an optimization to prevent additional client requests by including some additional useful information about each milestone.

One option here is to make a feature request through Rally's support team to add TargetDate to that set of denormalized data in the _tagsNameArray.

In the meantime your best course of action is probably to create an additional store to read the milestones in your workspace, fetching TargetDate and then use that store to look up the TargetDate for any milestone attached to a story in your first store.

Here's some code to do that lookup:

```
var estimatedTasksQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'UserStory',
    limit: Infinity,
    fetch: [ 'Milestones', 'AcceptedDate', 'PlanEstimate', 'ScheduleState', 'Iteration'],
    filters: [ 
        {property: 'DirectChildrenCount',
         operator: '=',
         value: '0'}
    ]
});

estimatedTasksQuery.load({
    callback: function() {
        //load milestones
        var milestoneStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'milestone',
            context: {
                project: null
            },
            fetch: ['TargetDate'],
            limit: Infinity
        });
        milestoneStore.load().then({
            success: function() {
                //loop over each story
                _.each(estimatedTasksQuery.getRange(), function(storyRecord) {
                    var milestones = storyRecord.get('Milestones');

                    //loop over each milestone in the tagsNameArray
                    _.each(milestones._tagsNameArray, function(milestone) {

                        //look up the full milestone data in the store
                        var id = Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(milestone);
                        var fullMilestone = milestoneStore.getById(id);

                        //apply it into the story record
                        Ext.apply(milestone, fullMilestone.getData());
                    });
                }); 

                //at this point all the data should be stitched together
                //example:
                _.each(estimatedTasksQuery.getRange(), function(storyRecord) {
                    _.each(storyRecord.get('Milestones')._tagsNameArray, function(milestone) {
                        console.log(milestone);
                    });
                });
             }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm, and how may i match the milestones of my new ws call to the ones assigned for each story?

Comment: added an example of creating and loading a store with milestones

Comment: In addition, will it work if I attach this code you wrote into my "estimatedTasksQuery.load({"?

Comment: Please take a look in the update i made in my question thks

Comment: If you're getting failures for Rally.data.wsapi.Store you must be using an older version of the SDK.  Rally.data.WsapiDataStore should work in its place.  Did you get it working?

Comment: Actually not. I cant figure out how to declare my UserStory sotre in a way that it will link both stores. Dont know how "storyRecord" will be ready with the stories data.

Comment: i updated it to put the whole thing together.  the example line at the bottom should show how to access all the data right from a story record.

Comment: i'm calling this under  afterRender: function() { ... } and its not reaching 'success: function() {' :/

Comment: sorry, had a tiny syntax error.  the above code i was able to get to work successfully.

Comment: still not workin. it may be my sdk version. <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>

Comment: ah, yeah i was testing against 2.0...  can you upgrade?